# Subqueries with Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

I have looked around on the internet for a while for a way to make this query work but am unable to work it out so far. I am trying to return the item descriptions and the quantity of items sold, This is what I have got at the moment:

```
SELECT itemdesc, quantity, (SELECT COUNT(quantity) FROM invoiceitem
WHERE invoiceitem.itemno = item.itemno 
GROUP BY COUNT(invoiceitem.quantity)) Quantity
FROM item;
```

I am very lost at the moment, not sure if I am even linking the right tables together, can provide an ER Diagram if it helps, any help would be greatly appreciated, thankyou.

ANSWER:

```
SELECT item.itemdesc, (SELECT SUM(invoiceitem.quantity) FROM invoiceitem 
WHERE invoiceitem.itemno = item.itemno
GROUP BY item.itemdesc) Quantity
FROM item
ORDER BY quantity;
```

Thankyou all!

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot Here is my Diagram: https://imgur.com/a/YCmSgpr and my expected output would be two columns, one with the 'itemdesc' and the second as the total quantity of items sold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer query:

```sql
SELECT itemdesc,
       quantity
       /* ignoring the subquery */
FROM   item;
```

Will not work as the `item` table does not have a `quantity` column.

If you intended to use the `itemprice` column then your query would be:

```sql
SELECT itemdesc,
       itemprice,
       ( SELECT COUNT(quantity)
         FROM   invoiceitem
         WHERE invoiceitem.itemno = item.itemno
       ) AS Quantity
FROM   item
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item (
  itemno PRIMARY KEY,
  itemdesc,
  itemprice
) AS
SELECT 1, 'ItemA', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ItemB', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'ItemC', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'ItemD', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'ItemE', 5 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE invoiceitem( itemno, quantity ) AS
SELECT 1, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ITEMDESC | ITEMPRICE | QUANTITY
> :------- | --------: | -------:
> ItemA    |         1 |        3
> ItemB    |         2 |        0
> ItemC    |         3 |        1
> ItemD    |         4 |        1
> ItemE    |         5 |        0
> ```

And equivalent query using a join would be (assuming that `item.itemno` is a primary key):

```sql
SELECT MAX( i.itemdesc ) AS itemdesc,
       MAX( i.itemprice ) AS itemprice,
       COUNT(ii.quantity) AS Quantity
FROM   item i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN invoiceitem ii
       ON ( ii.itemno = i.itemno )
GROUP BY i.itemno
```

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` to join the corresponding rows with zero items in the `invoiceitem` table.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83e3ec0ea0c3aa9508da7a8dd1aafc08)*

Comment: Thankyou very much, well explained. I dropped the quantity from where you said to and changed what I was grouping by as that was incorrect aswell, then got output and realised I should be using SUM() rather than COUNT(), thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Group by like below should work. Please check.

```
select
  item.itemdesc, count(invoiceitem.quantity) Quantity
from
  item item
  join invoiceitem invoiceitem on item.itemno = invoiceitem.itemno
group by
  item.itemdesc
```

Thanks

Comment: Thankyou very much, that is the output I am looking for. Would you happen to know how to achieve this same output with a subquery rather than the join? Purely just for educational purposes, I much prefer to use the join method as you have shown

Comment: Please see if this works.

SELECT 
  item.itemdesc, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(invoiceitem.quantity) 
    FROM 
      invoiceitem invoiceitem
    WHERE 
      invoiceitem.itemno = item.itemno 
  ) Quantity
FROM 
  item item;

Comment: This query is not the same as using the sub-query as the `JOIN` is wrong.

Comment: Yes left outer join is right to select item with zero quantities. Think, sum() should be used instead of count() to get the quantity of items sold. Is that what is expected?